# asp.net mvc2 is ValidateInput attribute is secure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Since I install TinyMCE on my asp.net mvc2 project,

I got this error

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
>   client

To get rid of it, I need to put this attribute on each controllers

```
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    [AllLocationAuthorizeAttribute]
    public class LocationController : Controller
    {
```

First question. Is it secure to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

[AllowHtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) attribute is best to fit.

ASP MVC automatically protects possible script inputs and throw exception. You can turn off it by using AllowHtmlAttribute or ValidateInputAttribute(false).

Razor engine will automatically encode strings like @model.SomeProperty, as it do HtmlHelper.Methods().

After encoding `<script>` will be `&lt;script&gt;` So in most cases there is no way to panic.

Helpfull links: [ValidateInput and AllowHtml](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/2NH8130313-Html-submission-by-ValidateInput-and-AllowHtml-attribute-in-MVC4.html),   [Prevent XSS attacks](http://thirum.wordpress.com/2013/10/24/how-asp-net-mvc-prevents-cross-site-scriptingxss-attack/)